# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable python class method

Tags: python

I have the following class methods:

```
def queryCollection(self, query_string={}, distinct_output = "_id"):
    output_array = []
    for property in self.coll.find(query_string).distinct(distinct_output):
        output_array.append(property)
    return set(output_array)

def smallDateQuery(self):
    x = self.queryCollection( { "created_at": {"$gte" : datetime(2015, 3, 1), "$lt": datetime(2015, 3, 30)}} )
    return x
```

When I call the first one, it works:

```
x = user.queryCollection({ "created_at": {"$gte" : datetime(2015, 3, 1), "$lt": datetime(2015, 3, 30)}})
print len(x)
```

When I call the second, it does not:

```
y = user.smallDateQuery()
print len(y)
quit()
```

I get the following error:

```
 x = self.queryCollection( { "created_at": {"$gte" : datetime(2015, 3, 1), "$lt": datetime(2015, 3, 30)}} )
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Have you tried splitting it into more separate steps so see what the uncallable object is? How did you import `datetime`?

Comment: nice catch!!!  on the class module, I just had `import Datetime` but on the main module I had `from datetime import datetime`.  Changed the class module and it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, since you're putting the contents of `output_array` into a set, why not do it directly? Eg, `output_set = set()` `for property in thingy: output_set.add(property)`. Also, beware of the [dangers of default mutable arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument), although it doesn't matter here since you don't modify `query_string` in `queryCollection()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have

```
import datetime
```

in which case you should use

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1)
```

The error arises because `datetime` is a module, the function to call is `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: Technically, `datetime.datetime` is a class, not a function.